# flutter-firestore: how to retrieve map field and array field

Tags: arrays, flutter, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, get

The following is the way I saved user's `geohash` and `geopoint` in firestore.

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve `g.geohash` or `g.geopoint` from firestore.

For example, if I want to read field `intro`, I write code this way;

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('...').doc(..).data()['intro']
```

But I don't know how to retrieve `g.geohash` and `g.geopoint` from firestore. `g.geohash` is inside a map, and `g.geopoint` is an array inside a map. How can I retrieve a map field like `g.geohash` and array-inside-a-map field `g.geopoint` from my firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to read a subset of the fields in a document.
You have to get entire document and then use dot notation or FieldPath to get nested data:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        try {
          dynamic nested = snapshot.get(FieldPath(['g', 'geopoint']));
          } on StateError catch(e) {
            print('No nested field exists!');
          }
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```