# How to get the array field of the document in the firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am working in flutter and trying to get the array field of the document in the firestore. But having several problems in doing so:

1. Cannot assign this array of id strings from firestore into the List in flutter
2. every time I try to get the array field, for some strange reason the array field gets deleted from firestore.

Here is the code of the function:

```
static List<String> getChatingTiles(String currentUserId) {
    CollectionReference users = firestore.collection("users");
    List<String> sessionIdList = <String>[];
    //trying to get the array field of the document that has an id of currentUserId
    users.doc(currentUserId).get().then((snapshot) => {
       //trying to loop through the array called sessions and adding every string element into the list
       for(String elem in snapshot.data()['sessions']) {
         sessionIdList.add(elem)
       }
    });
    print("list is here :");
    print(sessionIdList);
    return sessionIdList;
  }
```

Comment: With the 1st issue, did the `sessionIdList` stay empty? Did your `elem` iteration got a non-null value or it's nullable. You should print inside the for loop as well to check the data. For the 2nd issue, this probably relate to some other firestore update logics that's not related to this code here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make this

```
sessionid = snapshot.data['sessions']
```

after getting the document snapshot then return it

Answer (score 0):

I sugest that you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648981/flutter-firestore-how-to-retrieve-map-field-and-array-field)  which is very similar to yours and the answer says:

> "There is no way to read a subset of the fields in a document. You have to get entire document and then use dot notation or FieldPath to get nested data:"